# Getting "AttributeError: 'MapDataset' object has no attribute 'prefetch'" when trying to decode tensorflow data

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tfrecord

I have a trained model and I am trying to run testing but I keep getting an error. This is my function that decodes the TFRecord data:

```
def getTestData(filename, dataSize, batch_size):

    dataset = tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset(filename).map(decodeTest).prefetch(batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(dataSize)

    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    return dataset
```

This is the error I got:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-2f1981301a24>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('H:/Documents/project/main.py', wdir='H:/Documents/project')

  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "H:/Documents/project/main.py", line 44, in <module>
    ts.test(netOut,x,y,sess, testSize,0)

  File "H:\Documents\project\testing\test.py", line 14, in test
    dataset = d.getTestData(test, testSize, 1)

  File "H:\Documents\project\readTF\readDataTF.py", line 26, in getTestData
    dataset = tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset(filename).map(decodeTest).prefetch(batch_size)

AttributeError: 'MapDataset' object has no attribute 'prefetch'
```

Then i removed the .prefetch(batch_size) and got this error instead.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-2f1981301a24>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('H:/Documents/project/main.py', wdir='H:/Documents/project')

  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "H:/Documents/project/main.py", line 44, in <module>
    ts.test(netOut,x,y,sess, testSize,0)

  File "H:\Documents\project\testing\test.py", line 17, in test
    sess.run(iterator.initializer)

  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 789, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)

  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 997, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)

  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1132, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)

  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1152, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)

NotFoundError: Function tf_map_func_f6e35dc6 is not defined.
     [[Node: MapDataset = MapDataset[Targuments=[], f=tf_map_func_f6e35dc6[], output_shapes=[[96], [64], [32]], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](TFRecordDataset)]]

Caused by op 'MapDataset', defined at:
  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 231, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\ipython\start_kernel.py", line 227, in main
    kernel.start()
  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 477, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py", line 177, in start
    super(ZMQIOLoop, self).start()
  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 888, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 440, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 472, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\zmqstream.py", line 414, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\tornado\stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 235, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 533, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2717, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2827, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-1-2f1981301a24>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('H:/Documents/project/main.py', wdir='H:/Documents/project')
  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "H:/Documents/project/main.py", line 44, in <module>
    ts.test(netOut,x,y,sess, testSize,0)
  File "H:\Documents\project\testing\test.py", line 15, in test
    iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\data\python\ops\dataset_ops.py", line 396, in make_initializable_iterator
    return Iterator.from_dataset(self, shared_name)
  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\data\python\ops\dataset_ops.py", line 98, in from_dataset
    initializer = gen_dataset_ops.make_iterator(dataset.make_dataset_resource(),
  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\data\python\ops\dataset_ops.py", line 1153, in make_dataset_resource
    self._input_dataset.make_dataset_resource(),
  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\data\python\ops\dataset_ops.py", line 1076, in make_dataset_resource
    self._input_dataset.make_dataset_resource(),
  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\data\python\ops\dataset_ops.py", line 1457, in make_dataset_resource
    output_shapes=nest.flatten(self.output_shapes))
  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_dataset_ops.py", line 297, in map_dataset
    output_shapes=output_shapes, name=name)
  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2506, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\apps\Miniconda2\envs\tensorflowGPU\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1269, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Function tf_map_func_f6e35dc6 is not defined.
     [[Node: MapDataset = MapDataset[Targuments=[], f=tf_map_func_f6e35dc6[], output_shapes=[[96], [64], [32]], output_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](TFRecordDataset)]]
```

I am using TensorFlow version 1.2 and used a very similar function when decoding my training data and didnt get any errors so I am not sure what the problem is this time. (I can't upgrade to version 1.4 so I need a solution for 1.2.)

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The [`Dataset.prefetch()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) method was introduced in TensorFlow 1.4, so to run that exact code fragment you will need to upgrade. Many performance-related optimizations were added in TensorFlow 1.4 and later.

As an alternative, you can use the (now-removed) [`output_buffer_size`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/Dataset) argument to `map()`, which acts as a prefetch buffer:

```
def getTestData(filename, dataSize, batch_size):
    dataset = tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset(filename)

    # NOTE: This signature for `Dataset.map()` has been deprecated, and will not
    # work in TensorFlow 1.7 or later.
    dataset = dataset.map(decodeTest, output_buffer_size=batch_size)

    dataset = dataset.shuffle(dataSize)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    return dataset
```

The `NotFoundError` is a bug that was [fixed](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12373#issuecomment-323220087) in TensorFlow 1.3. To work around it, you must define all datasets *before* creating a `tf.Session` in your program.